# Most generic possible/meaningful signature for a generic sorting function

Tags: sorting, haskell, generic-list

I've done quite a bit of googling to come up with some hints/examples, to no avail so far.

Is there a more generic way to implement a sorting algorithm than one based on lists? I could just go with `sortGeneric :: IsList l => l a -> l a` but that seems like a bad idea because `IsList` is nothing more than support for `OverloadedLists`.

Maybe I should be just asking about sorting a `Traversable t => t a`?

Comment: `(Ord a, Traversable f) => f a -> f a` works, of course. With `lens`, `over (partsOf traverse) sort` implements it, I don't know though how often could this be useful.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [How to Keep your Neighbours in Order](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2628163) in which McBride defines a universe of trees for which the leaves are sorted by construction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You certainly can sort an arbitrary `Traversable` by folding over it to produce a list, vector, or heap, and then using `mapAccumL` or `mapAccumR` to put all the elements back. The trouble is that this may be less efficient than sorting the container directly.

```
import qualified Data.PQueue.Min as Q
import Data.Foldable (toList)
import Data.Traversable (Traversable (..))
import Data.Tuple (swap)
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict

sort xs = mapAccumL' go (Q.fromList . toList $ xs) xs where
  go h _ = swap $ Q.deleteFindMin h

mapAccumL' :: Traversable t =>
              (a -> b -> (a, c)) -> a -> t b -> t c
mapAccumL' f s t = flip evalState s $
   traverse (\q -> state $ swap . flip f q) t
```

Note that the uses of `toList` and `fromList` are purely for convenience, and the lists involved are pretty likely never to actually be allocated.

Comment: so I guess the fact no-one seems to care about it (at least considering Hackage and based on my search results), it's probably not something too useful. do you think that's a fair assessment?

Comment: @ErikAllik, it only seems to make sense to sort `Traversable` containers that actually represent sequences, rather than maps or whatever. These tend to have their own sorting functions.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sortGeneric :: (Ord a, Traversable t) => t a -> t a
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - _Is there a more generic way to implement a sorting algorithm than one based on lists?_